# Firebase Analytics incorrectly logs engagement time while app is not active

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

My app is using Firebase Analytics and linked with BigQuery. I found in BigQuery log that sometimes my app kept logging engagement time event when the app seems to be inactive. The behavior can be divided into 2 patterns:

**Pattern 1:** App keeps sending `user_engagement` event every one hour after app inactive.

**Pattern 2:** App was inactive for a long time (>1 hour). But when user come back, my app sent the first `screen_view` event with incorrect `engagement_time_msec` = ~amount of time since app last active.

Anyone has any idea what I could do wrong in my app. Since Firebase Analytics is not open source, I have no idea how this behavior could happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the root cause of incorrect engagement time. I found that Firebase Android SDK is not logging engagement time correctly when [disable screen view tracking](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews#disable_screenview_tracking). I filed an issue [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3240).

If you really need to disable auto screen tracking, you can use workaround I found below.

**Warning** This workaround may have side effect. Use it at your own risk.

I removed the following line from AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<meta-data android:name="google_analytics_automatic_screen_reporting_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

Then, use the following code in Activity's onResume for disabling automatic screen reporting instead.

```
override fun onResume() {
    FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false)
    super.onResume()
    FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
}
```

Comment: Have you been using this over the past year? Any side effects so far? I've run into the same issue myself now :(

Comment: @sammiepls Having use this solution for more than a year now. I don't notice any side effect. But I'm only using Analytics data in GA dashboard, and sometimes query the raw Analytics events from BigQuery. I don't know if there is any side effect in other features that using data from Analytics (e.g. Remote Config, A/B Testing, ...)

Comment: this is bug on Firebase side. Please see github: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3240